# How to get mysql import output

Tags: php, mysql, bash, shell

I am trying to create an app which dumps a database and then imports it somewhere. I did that but i got stuck in creating a real time output of the process. The way i am doing it right now is:

```
$command = "ssh -l ssh_user host -o ConnectTimeout=10 'mysqldump --user source_user --host source_host -ppassword --single-transaction --extended-insert --skip-add-drop-table --verbose source_db > /tmp/export_filename.sql; mysql -h target_host -u target_user -ppassword --execute="CREATE DATABASE new_db"; pv /tmp/export_filename.sql | mysql -h target_host -u target_user -ppassword new_db; rm -f /tmp/export_filename.sql'"

Process::fromShellCommandline($command)->run(function($buffer) use($output){
   $output .= '';
});
```

Process is a package from Symfony and it lets me run commands straight from here. Mysqldump gives me the output i need. However the import does not. I have tried to use pv in order to get a progress bar of the process but i don't receive it because (i think) i am running the command through ssh. Thank you.

Comment: Try to pair down your problem. Does it work without php? does it work without ssh? Is  pv working "correctly" in the sense that it's doing what you want? are you able to capture stdout/stderr from pv? ...etc  Theres a lot more debugging you can do that will allow you to ask a more specific question.

Comment: I have run the command outside of php. It doesnt output pv because i am running it through ssh. It doesn't have to do with Process. It does work without ssh

Comment: pv outputs to stderr. are you capturing stderr? (I don't know anything about Process)

Comment: i have succeded to get the pv output using the -f flag